# ASP classic CDO Email messaging use UTF-8 in textbody

Tags: asp-classic

How can i send email by using UTF-8 charset. Kindly note that I need to use it in textbody and not in htmlbody.

Everythings working fine if I uses it in htmlbody but when I tried to used textbody. I got aschii code character

```
objCDOMailer.TextBody  = "test - Rozwiązanie"  >> having a problem
objCDOMailer.HTMLBody  = "test - Rozwiązanie"  >> dont have a problem
```

I used the code below for both above.

```
  objMail.BodyPartCharset = "UTF-8"
```

Answer (score 5):

use

```
bjCDOMailer.TextBodyPart.Charset = "utf-8"
```

for charcter encoding.

```
objCDOMailer.BodyPart.Charset = "utf-8" 
objCDOMailer.HTMLBodyPart.Charset = "utf-8"
```

Above's are not working .

Comment: This is correct answer be it a bit unclear. Basically you have to set the encoding of the Body part you wish to be changed. Changing `HTMLBodyPart` when it's `TextBodyPart` that has the problem will do nothing. It's important to remember that E-mails can contain multiple Body parts to support Plain Text, RTF, HTML etc each with their own encodings *(not just character encodings but transfer encodings as well)*.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the encoding individually for TextBody and HTMLBody

```
objCDOMailer.BodyPart.Charset = "utf-8" 
bjCDOMailer.TextBodyPart.Charset = "utf-8" 
objCDOMailer.HTMLBodyPart.Charset = "utf-8"
```

Comment: thanks for this.. objCDOMailer.TextBodyPart.Charset = "utf-8" is not working  but HTMLBODY is working..

Comment: When i have used objCDOMailer.HTMLBodyPart.Charset = "utf-8" I can't received mail.In short  it's not working

Comment: Number of people coding that don't understand encoding basics is concerning to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 2019. IIS 10.

Enough only

```
objCDO.BodyPart.Charset = "utf-8"
```

plus your ASP file/pages must be saved with encoding: Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) Codepage 65001