# Pound signs changing to hashes over email

Tags: email, encoding, asp-classic, cdo.message

The following is in a file all on its own:

```
<%
Dim mailtest
Set mailtest = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
mailtest.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")=2
mailtest.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver")="localhost" 
mailtest.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport")=25
mailtest.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate")=0
mailtest.Configuration.Fields.Update
mailtest.Subject = "Test email"
mailtest.From = "test@test.com"
mailtest.To = "test@test.com"
mailtest.HTMLBody = "£££"
mailtest.Send
%>
```

I'm using smtp4dev to receive the emails. When I open the email, the body is simply "###".

What on earth could be causing this? I could understand if they were changing to question marks or something due to encoding issues, but why might they be changing to hashes?

Comment: try using `&pound;` in place of symbol

Comment: Since "pound sign" is another name for the # symbol, your question title is... confusing. :)

Comment: @Karthikeyan.V Thanks, this worked! As an aside, will this work in all encodings? i.e. If a browser/email client sees `&pound;` will it display it correctly even if UTF-8 hasn't been specified?

Comment: It'll work as long as you're sending html emails.  Obviously it won't work for text emails, or if the message is received by a text only client.  Take a look at this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9061974/asp-classic-cdo-email-messaging-use-utf-8-in-textbody