# encoding problem for SUBJECT of email using CDO

Tags: vbscript, character-encoding, cdo.message

Using vbscript (asp) with CDO I have problem with encoding in **SUBJECT** of email. I have used two solutions for BODY part of email and both works but non of them works for SUBJECT part.

First solution: Endcoding characters of email BODY using chrw (not working for **subject**):

```
for x=1567 to 1785
encoded="&#" & x & ";"
Body= Replace(Body, chrw(x), encoded, 1, -1, 1)
next
```

Second solution: setting HTMLBodyPart encoding:

```
objMessage.HTMLBodyPart.Charset = "utf-8"
```

is there something similar for SUBJECT part of email (e.g. `objMessage.SubjectPart.Charset`)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP classic CDO Email messaging use UTF-8 in textbody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9061974/asp-classic-cdo-email-messaging-use-utf-8-in-textbody)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
objMessage.TextBodyPart.Charset = "utf-8"
```

or simply:

```
objMessage.BodyPart.Charset = "utf-8"
```

It has been documented elsewhere that modifying the Charset of the TextBodyPart also impacts (the plain/text) Subject.

Hope this helps.